# OOP structure: inheritance and encapsulation

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

I'm starting a new project and also trying to get a better understanding of OOP in PHP. What I really want to see in action is the pros and cons of *encapsulation*. My ideal goal is to see there is no *class-property* exposed to the global scope, so there should be only *methods* publicly available to others, and they will rely on *private* or *protected* class-properties.

The other thing that I'm really looking into is to have a good *inheritance* as well; However I'm facing difficultly on how to combine both at the same design -- probably I have a wrong understanding or too much expectations from inheritance. To picture it better imaging the following structure:

1. Class `App` is the base class.
2. I have a couple of other classes like `Storage` class also, which they all *extends* `App` class.
3. Underneath, I have a MVC structure as well. So I want to have access to `Storage` methods just inside of my `Model` class, ideally by getting use of *inheritance* not *dependency injection* for example.

Now if I want to have my `Storage` methods available to others, I can simply make a public property in the `App` class and store the `Storage` instance in there, so every other class can simply access all the `Storage` methods, but I want to avoid it and implement a true encapsulation and see how it works in the real world.

On the other hand I want to have [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) on board as well. If I implement even just a single method in the `App` class that somehow gives you access to the `Storage` class for example, then I'm violating SRP, because that's not the business of `App` class -- `App` can't see the child methods, so I need to provide a way of accessing it.

Also in the above case, whenever I extend the `App` in another class, then I have to come back to the `App` class and provide some form interface to that class as well. That means touching an already-working code and I think it's not a good practice at all unless you want to debug the code, but not for adding features or even worst: when you're extending that class by others.

So the question is can I implement such a design without any compromise, and ideally in a battle-tested structure?

Comment: Just curious, how it comes to be too broad to get a close vote? Can I rephrase the question in a way that makes more sense? Or how can I narrow it down in a meaningful way?

Comment: Because there are a lot of different answers to your question, and a lot of it will result in opinion based answers.  Also, this technically isn't the correct forum for the question.  I believe it would be better suited for [Programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the explanation. I thought it will have a clear answer, either it's possible in a well-known structure, or it will be tricky otherwise. But hope to get some input here before it closes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key principles in OOP are encapsulation, cohesion, and coupling. Encapsulation is a protection mechanism. You restrict access to the internals of a class (or an instance of a class) from external actors. Cohesion describes how related the methods/properties of the class are. SRP is an expression of cohesion.  Coupling is how much interaction classes (or instances of them) have with each other.  You need some, but want them loosely coupled.  Dependency injection is one way of keeping your classes loosely coupled. For example, you inject dependencies, not create them internally so that the consuming class doesn't have intimate knowledge of how the class it is dependent on is created (and thus have to change if the creation logic changes).  Inheritance isn't strictly necessary for OOP but it allows *related* classes to share behavior; it's defined by an *is-a* relationship between two classes, for example, a `Car` is a specialization of a `Vehicle`.

Your idea of having all classes inherit from a single base class, other than a simple `object` class to give them common behaviors like equality and duplication, is a violation of the loose coupling principle and certainly is a bad example of inheritance. A storage mechanism is NOT an app.  An app might *have* a storage mechanism, so it would be an example of a *has-a* relationship or composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Great! I knew that I lack a proper understanding of how inheritance should be implemented. Thanks a lot, it was so brief but extremely useful.

Comment: Think of the behaviour of each object. Do "App" and "Storage" share behaviour? If not then they are not the same type of object, and should not be related by inheritance. It is also good to avoid "God objects", you shouldn't need an object representing the "program" or the "application" etc. The application is all your objects running, it (normally) doesn't need its own object representation.